# Rate limit in laravel 8 not works for the routes with post method

Tags: laravel, post, rate-limiting

Please check the following code for rate limiter

```
RateLimiter::for('api', function (Request $request) {
    return [
        // Rate limiter based on Client IP Address
        Limit::perMinute(env('IP_ADDR_RATE_LIMITER_PER_MINUTE', 60))->by($request->ip())->response(function () {
            ....
        }),
        // Rate limiter based on API key/User
        Limit::perMinute(env('API_KEY_RATE_LIMITER_PER_MINUTE', 60))->by($request->input('key'))->response(function () {
            ...
        })
    ];
});
```

Route config in api.php

```
Route::post('/temporalrisk/v1', [TemporalRouteRiskV1::class, 'postMethod'])->middleware('key')->name('temporalrouteriskv1.index');
```

Can someone help me to resolve the above issue to set rate limit for routes with post method?

Comment: you must write code [ return response('Custom response...', 429); ] in functions

Answer (score -1):

This might help you:

```
RateLimiter::for('global', function (Request $request) {
    return Limit::perMinute(1000)->response(function () {
        return response('Custom response...', 429);
    });
});
```

For more about rate-limiting :

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#rate-limiting